# MuiPrivateTabScrollButton overwite the width and flex property in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- I am trying to overwrite the css of MuiPrivateTabScrollButton.
- but this class is generated from material ui so I am not able to overwite.
- even I debugged by putting border colors and find out the fix, but still  I am not able to findout.
- all my code is in **tab-demo.js**
- Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/n5l8znn2y0

**update 1: removed unnecessary code for easy debugging** https://codesandbox.io/s/8xw88yl9j0

```
MuiPrivateTabScrollButton: {
width: "0 !important"
},

tabRoot: {
    textTransform: "initial",
    width: "stretch",
    display: "flex",
    flex: 1,
    border: "1px solid red",

    "&:hover": {
      color: "red",
      opacity: 1,
      textTransform: "initial"
    },
    "&$tabSelected": {
      color: "red",
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
      textTransform: "capitalize"
    },
    "&:focus": {
      color: "red",
      textTransform: "capitalize"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Your CodeSandbox should contain the **minimal** amount necessary to show the specific problem in your question.

Comment: @RyanCogswell hey I updated the code, can you help me now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for each Material-UI component is a CSS section that indicates the classes that can be passed in to control CSS for different aspects. [Here is that documentation for Tabs.](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#css)

In particular you care about:

> scrollButtons Styles applied to the ScrollButtonComponent component.

You then need to specify the appropriate class via the `classes` property.

For instance if you have the following in the styles passed to `withStyles`:

```
const styles = theme => ({

  tabsScrollButton: {
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }
};
```

Then you would leverage that class like the following:

```
<Tabs
   classes={{ scrollButtons: props.classes.tabsScrollButton }}
>
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: hey thanks so much, since you have given negative masrk for other questions...I am not able to post further :(